# How to disable loggers of a class or of whole package?

Tags: java, apache-commons-logging

I am using [*Apache Commons Logging ™*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/). For now I wanted to use [`SimpleLog`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.html) implementation, but when I changed the level, loggers from the libraries came out. I want it to turn them off.

Is there a easy way to change log level for whole package (can Log4j do that)?

I have tried to set

> org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.foo=fatal

in the property files to disable (setting to fatal is OK) `foo` logger, but it doesn't work (foo is a  name of logger that appears in output : `[INFO] foo - Message`).

Comment: If you've got the time I'd recommend looking at SLF4J. http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html - it acts as a meta-layer above an actual logging framework - including log4j.   Its very easy to set up. Yes - it is possible with log4j to set logging levels at package level. It also supports an 'off' level.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could have approve this answer, but this is a comment..

Answer (score 125, accepted):

In Log4j you can specify a logging level for specified package, class or logger identified by string. You just simply write this in log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.<your package> = DEBUG|INFO|OFF|WARN...
```

Comment: How can I get a handle to this logger in my class?

Answer (score 20):

You should use:

```
log4j.logger.foo = OFF
```

Please note that "foo" does not need to be a package, or a class, but is an arbitrary String. We e.g. have a logger named "SQL" that is called from many classes.

Comment: I'd like to do it in simplelog. But I see that changing it to log4j is a solution.

Comment: log4j is the most used logging framework in the world. Just stick with what everyone uses, and you profit from plugins, custom appenders, filters, etc.

Comment: The key term is `OFF` which is missing from top-voted answer.

Answer (score 18):

If you use Spring Boot, you may set to `OFF` in application.properties file, by using `logging.level.<package-or-class-name>=OFF` Example:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer=OFF
```

Reference:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.log-levels

Answer (score 2):

I am using Log4j2 and the configuration file I use with is `resources/log4j2.xml`.

My problem was disabling all logs from a third-party dependency `com.pesky.and.chatty.package` which was outputting lots of logs in `DEBUG` and `INFO` levels.

I searched far and wide until I found how to disable all logs from that package.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%p %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="warn" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.pesky.and.chatty.package" level="OFF" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Not a single peep from `com.pesky.and.chatty.package` anymore!

Note additivity set to `OFF` for the given Logger. This ensures the logs aren't propagated to the Root and won't end up printed there. Really sneaky issue to debug!

Comment: log4j2.properties didn't work for me in my maven project but this solution did. Thanks.

Comment: @sam It depends what logging framework you use and which one is configured for the project. In my case, my `pom.xml` also had to include some extra packages to make sure log4j2 is properly set as the logger.

Answer (score 1):

Use of SimpleLog from Commons Logging requires two configuration files unless you are using some system properties. The files are: commons-logging.properties and simplelog.properties.
The log level properties you have indicated should be placed in simplelog.properties like:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.foo=warn
```

where "foo" is the logger name. Generally, this is the package or package and class name. In the following example, everything under the com.stackoverflow.utils package is set to **info** whereas com.stackoverflow.servlet.Dispatcher is specifically set to **warn**:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.com.stackoverflow.utils=info 
org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.com.stackoverflow.servlet.Dispatcher=warn
```

The commons-logging.properties file should contain:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
```

Documentation [here](http://commons.apache.org/logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SimpleLog.html) and [here](http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html#Configuration).

Comment: I know. The problem is how to do  sth like "log4j.logger.<your package> = DEBUG|INFO|OFF|WARN..." in SimpleLog.

Comment: I created a small project and tested package-level log control and it works as desired. I have updated my example to illustrate hierarchical log level control. If it is not working this way in your environment, it is likely not detecting your simplelog.properties. When you change other values in there, does it affect the output (e.g. enable/disable dates w/ org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true/false)?