# Liferay standard output polluted by PDFBox and PropsUtil

Tags: pdfbox, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

I wrote a Liferay module that imports JournalArticles (Web Content). While it works fine with most content, since I imported some particular content I get this:

```
15:36:13,901 ERROR [main][PDCIDFontType2:211] OpenType Layout tables used in font ABCDEE+?l?r ?S?V?b?N are not implemented in PDFBox and will be ignored
15:36:14,126 INFO  [main][PropsUtil:386] Global shared lib directory /home/nico/p/liferay/liferay-dxp-digital-enterprise-7.0-sp3/tomcat-8.0.32/lib/
15:36:14,128 INFO  [main][PropsUtil:397] Global lib directory /home/nico/p/liferay/liferay-dxp-digital-enterprise-7.0-sp3/tomcat-8.0.32/lib/ext/
15:36:14,131 INFO  [main][PropsUtil:420] Portal lib directory /home/nico/p/liferay/liferay-dxp-digital-enterprise-7.0-sp3/tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
```

If it was in the log I would simply configure logging to ignore it, but the above appears **in the standard output**, which pollutes my Gogo Shell.

It is the first time I see this kind of problem, as all other errors go to the Liferay log file rather than `System.out`.
Is there any way to avoid these errors being dumped into my standard output?

Comment: 1) you're not using the latest PDFBox version, the current one has that msg as INFO because it is not so important 2) only the first line is from PDFBox, the other ones are not 3) tell what logger you are using. If it is log4j, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972954/how-to-disable-loggers-of-a-class-or-of-whole-package

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: It is a Liferay question, I am not putting any blame on the PDFBox team :-) Liferay 7 SP3 indeed embeds the old PDFBox 2.0.3. PropsUtil is [a part of Liferay](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/util/PropsUtil.java#L420). Liferay uses log4j and `org.apache.pdfbox` is set to level `ERROR`.