# How to suppress local info logs from Sentry in Java?

Tags: java, sentry

I'm using [Sentry](https://sentry.io/) to log errors that occur in my code and every time I launch my application I see that Sentry logs information like

```
[main] INFO io.sentry.DefaultSentryClientFactory - Using an HTTPS connection to Sentry.
```

Is it possible to suppress this kind of logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which logging framework you are using but each of them offers a way to change the threshold for a specific package (or class), so you could just disable or raise it for `io.sentry.DefaultSentryClientFactory`. For example, here's one for log4j: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4973082/11958

PS: I work on `sentry-java` and I think those shouldn't be at the `INFO` level, honestly. I'll change that in a future release.