# Can we disable log4j logs only for kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm  using following properties for **Log4j**:

```
//log4j.properties

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I want to disable log messages only for **Kafka**, where as display my log messages being logged.

Answer (score 23):

you need to disable logger for both log4j and slf4j to disable kafka logging completely:

Add a **logback.xml** file in your resources dir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="kafka" level="OFF"/>
</configuration>
```

Add below to your **application.yaml / properties**:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: OFF
    org.springframework: OFF
    org.apache: OFF
    kafka: OFF
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the log level to `OFF` by adding this line:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=OFF
```

Compare: [How to disable loggers of a class or of whole package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972954/how-to-disable-loggers-of-a-class-or-of-whole-package)

Answer (score 0):

*A more detailed version from [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62401824/9549068)*

*. overall::

[image: overall]

1. 
Setup a simple Kafka Program (Completely from scratch)

2. 
**Add log4j dependency** 
*(using Spring, so no version)*

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

3. 
**Add the logback.xml** 
*(same as answer above; seems like can comment out some not needed)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
<!--     <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/> -->
    <logger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>
<!--     <logger name="kafka" level="WARN"/> -->
</configuration>
```

*. note::

1. **Add log4j dependency** is needed
2. tried adding **`application.properties` / `log4j.properties`** in `src/main/resources`, seems **not** playing any effect

   so, config like these didnt work for me::

   ```yaml
   #log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
   #log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   #log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   #log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
   #
   #log4j.logger.kafka=OFF
   #log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=OFF

   #logging.level.root=OFF
   #logging.level.org.springframework=OFF
   #logging.level.org.apache=OFF
   #logging.level.kafka=OFF
   ```

   placing them in a diff **folder location** neither worked (eg: direct under project folder / inside `src/main/java`)
3. I **didnt** find a **dynamic way** to add the config. (written inside programming code, instead of a file; neither in kafka config, nor in log4j getLogger)
4. place the file under **`src/main/resources`**
5. (though I am using Spring framework, I **didnt use the integrated Kafka**, & didnt ran it as Spring server -- just more like a normal Java application.)
6. (I dont know if there would be any **confliction** on the log4j (seems happened to me long before))

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we are using `ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate` to publish records to Kafka. And extra logs were being written by `TracingProducerInterceptor` which was registered in the bean of `ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate`

```
 @Bean
  public ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<YourModelEventKey, YourModelEvent> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate(
      final KafkaProperties properties) {
    var props = properties.buildProducerProperties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG, Collections.singletonList(TracingProducerInterceptor.class));
    return new ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<>(SenderOptions.create(props));
  }
```

Solution:
`logging.level.brave.Tracer=warn` for application.properties
and for application.yaml use below

```
logging.level
    brave.Tracer: warn
```

Note: we are interested only in warnings or errors. If you want, you can fully disable by setting `OFF`

Answer (score -4):

```
logging:
  level:
    root: OFF
    org.springframework: OFF
    org.apache: OFF
    kafka: OFF
```

This configuration works for me.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the second part of [Dean Jain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62401824/2227743).