# How to disable specific log message in Apereo CAS 6

Tags: logging, cas, apereo

I am using Apereo CAS 6.2. During startup there are many log messages. I want to disable this specific one:

```
INFO [org.apereo.cas.configuration.DefaultCasConfigurationPropertiesSourceLocator] - <Configuration files found at [/etc/cas/config] are [[file [/etc/cas/config/cas.properties]]] under profile(s) [[standalone]]>
```

It could not control it by log4j.xml file like other messages. Property logging.level.org.apereo.cas in cas.properties file also doesn`t affect on this line. Inside the docker container it is saved in the /tmp/logs/cas.log file. How can I turn off that message?

Comment: how about `logging.level.org.apereo.cas.configuration.DefaultCasConfigurationPropertiesSourceLocator=ERROR', would that works?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Judging from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972954/how-to-disable-loggers-of-a-class-or-of-whole-package, disabling of a class should be possible. Now you evne said that `logging.level.org.apereo.cas` does not work is weird, because I used that in my setup with no issue. Maybe your properties is not loaded correctly? Did you load other properties other than logging.level.org.apearo.cas?

Comment: Other properties are being loaded correctly. Logging.level.org.apereo.cas works but it does not affect this one line.

Comment: Ah I see that you the problem is, the issue comes in that, during the `DefaultCasConfigurationPropertiesSourceLocator` is loaded, cas.properties and other stuff is not yet loaded, so it is impossible to disable this line in `cas.properties`. Can you try do this: create a YAML file in `src/main/resources` called `application.yml`, put this in `logging.level.org.apereo.cas.configuration.DefaultCasConfigurationPropertiesSourceLocator: OFF` in. If still not works, also can try putting it in `bootstrap.yml` file, same folder